# How to find exponential formula coefficients?

Tags: excel, exponential

I have the following pairs of values:

```
 X      Y
 1      2736
 2      3124
 3      3560
 4      4047
 5      4594
 6      5205
 7      5890
 8      6658
 9      7518
10      8480
18     21741
32    108180
35    152237
36    170566
37    191068
38    214087
39    239838
40    268679
```

When I put these pairs in Excel, I get a exponential formula:

```
Y = 2559*e^(0.1167*X)
```

with an accuracy of 99,98%.
Is there a way to ask from Excel to provide a formula in the following format:

```
Y = (A/B)*C^X-D
```

If not, is it possible to convert the above formula to the wanted one?
Note, that I am not familiar with Matlab.

Answer (score 4):

You already have it !

```
A = 2559
B = 1
C = exp(0.1167)
D = 0
```

You'll see that it is equivalent to your formula Y = 2559*e^(0.1167*X), because e^(0.1167*X) =  (e^0.1167)^X